# Filter in controllers

Tags: angularjs, module, controller

Hi i really need integrate a filter in to my controller, but it been hard, 
I provide my controller and the filter that I  made few day  ago.
Thanks in advance!

```
 angular.module('tickets').controller('TicketsController', ['$scope',   '$filter', '$routeParams', '$interval', '$location', 'Authentication',  'Tickets',
function($scope, $filter , $routeParams, $interval, $location, Authentication, Tickets){ contenido del controlador}]);
```

The filter is as follows:

```
 .filter("filtroDate", function($filter) 
{
   return function(input)
 {
    //replace(/([^\"]*)(\d*)([^\w]*)/, replacer);
        $scope.diaActual = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        var salida = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.tickets, function(eachtime){


        var creado = $scope.tickets.creado =  pais.diaAnt.replace(/^\"  (.*)\"/,"$1");

        console.log("Creado :",$scope.tickets.creado);

        var diaTickete = $filter('date')(new Date(creado), 'yyyy-MM-dd');

        console.log("diaTickete :", diaTickete);


         if ($scope.diaActual === diaTickete ) {   

            salida.push($scope.tickets)
          }
        })
        return salida;
    }
});
```

Comment: Looking at your code, I think you´re misunderstanding the use of filters. You don´t have access to the $scope property here. A filter receives some input and maybe additional params, and returns a value... It looks like you´re doing a lot of $scope manipulation here, maybe you don´t need a filter at all. The main idea on filters is to use them on views, using the `pipe` syntax.

Comment: Have you read the angular documentation? You can find [lots of info on how to use and inject filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#using-filters-in-controllers-services-and-directives) on angular's site.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i was trying to use the filter in the controller to have access to the scope, thanks for the tips, I'm new on this world :)

Answer (score 0):

To integrate your filter in a controller is pretty straight forward, you´ll only need to inject the `$filter` service and get an instance of a given filter...

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($filter){
    var myFilter = $filter('filtroDate'); //this returns the filter function!
    var result = myFilter('some-input');
})
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help, finally I solved my problem, Many Thanks really (y)